# some files not founded in mysql module

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular

i developp a project with angular8 and mysql database with framework node.js backend,but when i try connect to database i have this error:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js Module
> not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'C:\Users\PRO\Desktop\commerce\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js Module not found:
> Error: Can't resolve 'net' in
> 'C:\Users\PRO\Desktop\commerce\node_modules\mysql\lib'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js Module not found: Error: Can't
> resolve 'tls' in
> 'C:\Users\PRO\Desktop\commerce\node_modules\mysql\lib'

databaseService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Utilisateur } from '../classes/utilisateur';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DatabaseService {

  constructor() { }

  connectToDatabase(){
  var mysql = require('mysql');
  var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "password",
  database: "ecommerce"
  });

  con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  else return con;
  });

  }
createUser(user:Utilisateur){
var con=this.connectToDatabase();
var sql="insert into utilisateur values(0,"+ 
user.nomClient+","+user.adresse+","
+user.telephone+","+ user.mail+","+user.username + "," +user.password + ")";
alert('vous etes inscrits avec succes !');

}
}
```

Comment: Are you using webpack? maybe you are missing some configuration

Comment: Diego bascans I'm not using webpack

Comment: Have you run `npm install` in your project root to ensure the necessary dependencies are installed? Also provide an example of your `package.json`